# Inserting multiple columns in the table error with query

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
ALTER TABLE  `mytable` ADD  
`telephone` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`date_of_annual_health_care_plan` DATE NOT NULL,
`first_language` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`interp_req` INT NOT NULL,
`religion` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`religious_considerations` VARCHAR ( 350 ) NOT NULL,
`diagnosis_and_associated_health_conditions` VARCHAR ( 500 ) NOT NULL,
`communcation` VARCHAR ( 350 ) NOT NULL,
`challenging_behaviours` VARCHAR ( 350 ) NOT NULL,
`medicare_number` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`pension_number` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`private_health_insurance` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`person_responsible` INT NOT NULL,
`person_res_name` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`person_res_address` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`person_res_telephone_h` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`person_res_telephone_w` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`person_res_telephone_m` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`person_res_email` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`decision_making_function` VARCHAR ( 250 ) NOT NULL,
`relative` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`guardian_name` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`guardian_address` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`guardian_telephone_h` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`guardian_telephone_w` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`guardian_telephone_m` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
`guardian_email` VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL
;
```

And I am getting the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '`date_of_annual_health_care_plan` DATE NOT NULL,
>   `first_language` VARCHAR ( 50 ' at line 3

Why am I receiving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prefix `ADD COLUMN` before each column in order to add multiple columns in one statement, like so:

```
ALTER TABLE  `mytable`
ADD COLUMN `telephone` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD COLUMN `date_of_annual_health_care_plan` DATE NOT NULL,
...
```

Also, I don't think you need backticks everywhere, since none of the names conflict with reserved words.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9fabd)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following query.
You Syntax was wrong.

```
ALTER TABLE  mytable 
ADD column telephone VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column date_of_annual_health_care_plan DATE NOT NULL,
ADD column first_language VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column interp_req INT NOT NULL,
ADD column religion VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column religious_considerations VARCHAR ( 350 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column diagnosis_and_associated_health_conditions VARCHAR ( 500 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column communcation VARCHAR ( 350 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column challenging_behaviours VARCHAR ( 350 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column medicare_number VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column pension_number VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column private_health_insurance VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column person_responsible INT NOT NULL,
ADD column person_res_name VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column person_res_address VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column person_res_telephone_h VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column person_res_telephone_w VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column person_res_telephone_m VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column person_res_email VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column decision_making_function VARCHAR ( 250 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column relative VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column guardian_name VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column guardian_address VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column guardian_telephone_h VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column guardian_telephone_w VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column guardian_telephone_m VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
ADD column guardian_email VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL;
```